# Propel ORM: exclude tables from migration

Tags: php, propel

Is there a way to exclude my wp_* tables (which are not part of the schema.xml) from the diff/migrate process?

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible in Propel 1.6 even if someone wrote a patch recently. Propel2 will probably handle that.

Comment: Could you link to that patch?